# When does a Lie bracket exist for a Frechet manifold?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Does a general Frechet manifold admit a Lie bracket? A bracket can certainly be constructed in certain cases, but my guess is that it is wrong to assume that one exists in general.